# Duplicate a page on Document using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm creating a PDF using iTextSharp. This PDF will have `n-pages` where all of the pages are exactly the same, except for a small text change. So I wanted to clone my `Document` object, do the change and add as a new page to the document, is it possible?

EDIT: To clarify a little what I have to do. I'm creating a document, and right now is on the memory as an `iTextSharp.Document` object. The user will save this to his computer (it is an web application) but in this case, the file that he will save should consiste of 3 pages, every  page with the same content, except for one Paragraph on the bottom that changes.

What I did now was recreating the tables\paragraphs etc on each page, of the document, what I wanted was get the `Document` I created representing one page, clone it 3 times, and join as pages on a document.

Comment: Maybe it's very easy, maybe it's very hard. It all depends on the nature of the *small text change* you want to apply. Can you elaborate?

Comment: One chunk of text will be changed on each page. But basically what I need more is to duplicate one page `n` times on the document. So for example, I create PAGE 1 and now I need PAGE 3 and 4 to be the same as PAGE 1.

Comment: What's keeping you from using `PdfSmartCopy` as indicated in my answer?

Comment: Doesn't `PdfSmartCopy` need a physical file to work? I do not have those, I'm doing everything on memory and sending to another funcion a MemoryStream which will be send to the response object

Comment: No, `PdfSmartCopy` needs a `PdfReader` instance. You can create such an instance using a `byte[]`. You can get a `byte[]` from a `MemoryStream` that holds a complete PDF. In the Java example in my answer, I have `reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());` and this also exists in C#.

Comment: Oh good, I will try this solution tomorrow then when I'm back at this code

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution. It may not be the solution you want, but... that's not our fault as you are making us guess regarding your intentions.

Suppose that you have a PDF document with a single page: [state.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/master/src/test/resources/pdfs/state.pdf)

You want to add some text to this page, so that it looks like this: [california.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/master/src/test/resources/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/cmp_flatten_form.pdf)

You don't want to do this once, but you want to do this multiple times, so that you get this: [united_states_2.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/master/src/test/resources/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/cmp_fill_flatten_merge2.pdf)

In that case, you need a combination of `PdfStamper` (to add the content to the single page) and `PdfSmartCopy` (to combine the different pages without bloating the document).

This is shown in the [FillFlattenMerge2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-using-forms-reporting#2750-fillflattenmerge2.java) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    PdfReader reader;
    PdfStamper stamper;
    AcroFields fields;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DATA));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // create a PDF in memory
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
        fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
        fields.setField("name", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("abbr", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("capital", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("city", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("population", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("surface", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("timezone1", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("timezone2", tokenizer.nextToken());
        fields.setField("dst", tokenizer.nextToken());
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
        // add the PDF to PdfCopy
        reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        reader.close();
    }
    br.close();
    document.close();
}
```

If this is not what you want, please clarify your question. In any case: this answer is one of the many possible correct interpretations of your question.